# Can the hover/active borders of form fields be customized and/or disabled?

Tags: infopath, custom-form, spfield, formatting

I'm really not crazy about field borders in forms.  In InfoPath, you can get rid of the borders, but then the row heights jump in the browser once the form is published to SharePoint.  So--reluctantly--I just make the borders white (or whatever the background color happens to be if not white).  But I still have to see that ugly border styling when a field is hovered over or actively selected.  What's the best way to disable or at least customize them (make them white to match the inactive border style)?

As a bonus, it would be great to also get rid of those awful "x"s that show up in active fields--they extend the width of a field past 100% and make cells to the right look wonky.